# Creating column on filtered pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

From an initial DataFrame loaded from a `csv` file,

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",sep=";")
```

I get a filtered copy with

```
df_filtered = df[df["filter_col_name"]== value]
```

However, when creating a new column using the `diff()` method,

```
df_filtered["diff"] = df_filtered["feature"].diff()
```

I get the following warning:

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

I notice also that the processing time is very long.

Surprisingly (at leat to me...), if I do the same thing on the non-filtered DataFrame, I runs fine.

How should I proceed to create a "diff" column on the filtered data?

Answer (score 1):

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

If you modify values in `df_filtered` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

```
#need process sliced df, return sliced df
df_filtered = df[df["filter_col_name"]== value].copy()
```

Or:

```
#need process sliced df, return all df
df.loc[df["filter_col_name"]== value, 'feature'] = 
df.loc[df["filter_col_name"]== value , 'feature'].diff()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'filter_col_name':[1,1,3],
                   'feature':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   C  D  E  F  feature  filter_col_name
0  7  1  5  7        4                1
1  8  3  3  4        5                1
2  9  5  6  3        6                3
```

```
value = 1

df_filtered = df[df["filter_col_name"]== value].copy()
df_filtered["diff"] = df_filtered["feature"].diff()
print (df_filtered)
   C  D  E  F  feature  filter_col_name  diff
0  7  1  5  7        4                1   NaN
1  8  3  3  4        5                1   1.0
```

---

```
value = 1

df.loc[df["filter_col_name"]== value, 'feature'] = 
df.loc[df["filter_col_name"]== value , 'feature'].diff()

print (df)
   C  D  E  F  feature  filter_col_name
0  7  1  5  7      NaN                1
1  8  3  3  4      1.0                1
2  9  5  6  3      6.0                3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
df_filtered.loc[:, "diff"] = df_filtered["feature"].diff()
```